# iPhone registerForRemoteNotificationTypes does not generate an error but does not fire delegate that gives device token

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-push-notifications, appdelegate, devicetoken

I am developing an iPhone app that needs push notification. I followed the instructions for creating the certifications and modifying the app ID. I am not totally sure I did this correctly, but I did follow the directions. Any idea how I can check to see if this is OK?

When I ran in the emulator I did get an error message saying that the emulator did not support push notifications. This was somewhat expected.

BTW: I have seem this question out there a few times. It always seems to be with a jail-broken phone. My phone is NOT jail-broken.

But when I debug on the iPhone the didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken method is never fired off. I will really appreciate some help. My code follows.

```
-(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application 
{    
   rootController.delegate = self;
   [window addSubview:rootController.view];
   [window makeKeyAndVisible];

   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] 
   registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
   (UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | 
     UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | 
     UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken 
{ 
   NSString *str = 
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",deviceToken];
    NSLog(str);
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)err 
{ 
    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Error: %@", err];
    NSLog(str);    
}
```

Comment: What certificate are you using to run the application? I think this may have an impact.

Answer (score 21):

Usually if `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` is never called, it is because you are using a provisioning profile that is not `APS-entitled`. If you app is a production app, it must be signed with a distribution profile for pushes to work. If it is a development app, you must sign it with a development profile.

**EDIT:** It is also worthy to note that the `provisioning profile` must use an explicit bundle id. Pushes sent to anything signed with a wildcard profile will not be delivered.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to replace the provisioning profile with the new one

Comment: This makes perfect sense except for the apparent fact that `didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:` doesn't get called in this case? Is this really so?

Comment: Yes it really so, no callback at all if you don't activate that capability

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue.

For me, it was the notification setting for the App had everything turned off.

If in the iOS settings app notifications are disabled, that method will not get called.

Once I turned on a notification type it started to work.

`Settings App->Notification Settings->[My App]`

Comment: @hasan, in the Settings iOS app. Its not so much a solution, but an explanation of the problem. If someone turns off notifications for your app, you don't get an error or a method call.

Comment: @hasan You're saying if a user turns off push notifications for my app, then neither didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken nor didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError will get called?

Comment: @PaulG that was my experience when I was looking at it.

Comment: Confirmed through multiple testing on a brand new device with app that is working on every other level except having the user turn off notifications. When they turned them off, device does NOT issue error or success. It quietly just does not call either.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [TN2265](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2265/_index.html), which has hints for debugging push notification problems. I had exactly this problem today and it turned out that WiFi was turned off on iPod Touch. Since you said you were working from an iPhone. that's probably not it, but it's worth checking out the tech note for additional possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

Check your firewall settings.

From [Scott K's Answer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2265/_index.html):

> If your iOS device is capable of using the cellular data network, 
>   check that it has an active cellular data plan. Turn off Wi-Fi in 
>   Settings and see if you can still browse the web with Safari, for 
>   example. On the other hand, if the push service is using Wi-Fi,  any
>   firewalls between your device or computer and the Internet  must allow
>   TCP traffic to and from port 5223.

Answer (score 1):

According to Apple's documentation "Troubleshooting Push Notifications" "If neither delegate callback application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken: nor application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError: is called, that means that this connection is not yet been establihed."..."The system may not have Internet connectivity..aiplane mode."

I'm seeing this behavior as well but NOT because of lack of internet connectivity but because, as IrFan pointed out, the notifications were disabled for the app, as soon as you enable the notifications, the method fires.

Solution
1) Do NOT rely on either of these delegate methods ever being called.
2) If, and when, you receive a delegate callback, act on it.
3) Lack of network connectivity, push notifications being disabled for the app, APS not enabled, or ?  will cause the delegates to NOT get called.

Answer (score 1):

If you're compiling using the iOS8+ SDK (eg xcode 6+), then the deprecated iOS7 API methods are *silently ignored* and you'll get no error.

You need something like this if you want to support iOS7 and 8:

```
// Have to explicitly use the iOS8 api as the deprecated API is silently ignored on iOS8, surprisingly.
if ([UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion.intValue >= 8) { // iOS8+ API.
    UIUserNotificationType types = UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge;
    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types categories:nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
} else { // iOS7.
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
        UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];
}
```

If you are having issues with `aps-environment` missing from your profile, you'll at least get a helpful error callback with `didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError`

Comment: In my case, I was missing the call to `registerUserNotificationSettings:` (I was under the assumption that I should daisy chain and call it from within the success callback). Calling `registerForRemoteNotifications` does not kickstart the registration process.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue in iOS 11.3 device where none of the delegate methods were getting called. So, according to Apple documentation :-

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2265/_index.html

> When the first push-capable app is installed, iOS or OS X attempts to establish a persistent network connection to the push service that will be shared by all push-capable apps on the system. If neither delegate callback application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken: nor application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError: is called, that means that this connection has not yet been established.

Further on,

> This is not necessarily an error condition. The system may not have Internet connectivity at all because it is out of range of any cell towers or Wi-Fi access points, or it may be in airplane mode. Instead of treating this as an error, your app should continue normally, disabling only that functionality that relies on push notifications.

**I tried connecting to other network** and again start performing register notification operation and Voila!, it worked like a charm. So, I guess there was a problem in registering for notification which was calling neither of the delegate methods.