# registerForRemoteNotifications() Callbacks not being called

Tags: apple-push-notifications, ios9, xcode7

This question has been asked (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224605/iphone-registerforremotenotificationtypes-does-not-generate-an-error-but-does-no) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6631710/push-notification-delegate-call-backs-are-not-getting-called)), but none of the solutions seems to apply to my setup.

I am developing an app in iOS 9 / Xcode7 (beta 5).

I have created an explicit App ID / bundle identifier.
(The app ID is automatically generated by Xcode, but is listen in the Developer Portal as `Xcode iOS App ID com mycompanyname mayappname`).

I have configured my target's "Capabilities" in Xcode to add support for push notifications.

I have configured my App ID in the developer portal to support push notifications:
I created and downloaded a development APNs certificate, and installed in my keychain (not sure this is needed? I thought this cert is intended for my server? But just to be safe in case it is needed at build time?)

I am running the app from Xcode on the device: iPhone 5s, iOS 9, 4G connectivity, Wi-Fi turned off (just in case).

My app is not listed in the device's Settings.app, "Notifications" section, so there's nothing I can enable there...

I initiate the registration process like this:

```
func application(application: UIApplication,
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?
        ) -> Bool
{
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        
    return true
}
```

I have implemented both:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData)
{

}
```

...and:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError)
{
       
}
```

and setup breakpoints/logs on both, but neither gets called.

What can be happening?

**EDIT:** It is working now, but only if I call ***both*** `registerForRemoteNotifications()` ***and*** `registerUserNotificationSettings()` at launch.

I was working under the assumtion that I should first call `registerForRemoteNotifications()`, and on success (i.e., `application(_:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken)`) I should in turn call `registerUserNotificationSettings()` to specify the types of notifications (and prompt the user). The docs do not make clear which of these two functions must be called first; in particular, the inline docs for `registerForRemoteNotifications()` say:

> [...] Call this method to initiate the registration process[...]

, which seems to suggest that it alone triggers the whole thing. However, the [programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW2) has the following step-by-step instructions:

> 1. Register the notification types your app supports using registerUserNotificationSettings:.
> 2. Register to receive push notifications via APNs by calling your app’s registerForRemoteNotifications method.
> 3. Store the device token returned to the app delegate by the server for a successful registration, or handle registration failure
>    gracefully.
> 4. Forward the device token to the app’s push provider.

---

#### Update (Jan 2015):

I moved on to another project so I didn't follow up the issue or find a definitive response. Still listening to any helpful info...

Comment: I'm seeing the exact same thing, using Xcode 7b5, and the workaround you mention in your edit fixes it for me as well.

Comment: Is it really a workaround, or is it how it is supposed to work? I am still confused...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close.

You need first to call `registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:` or  `registerUserNotificationSettings:` (iOS >=8)

And then call

```
registerForRemoteNotifications:
```

You have that example code:

```
   // Register the supported interaction types.

    UIUserNotificationType types = UIUserNotificationTypeBadge |

                 UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert;

    UIUserNotificationSettings *mySettings =

                [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types categories:nil];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:mySettings];



   // Register for remote notifications.

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
```

Via:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html

Answer (score 2):

Since this was originally answered,

```
registerUserNotificationSettings:
```

...has been deprecated, and,

```
requestAuthorizationWithOptions:completionHandler: // Objective C
```

...should now be used, or the Swift equivalent,

```
requestAuthorization(options:completionHandler:) // Swift
```

Here's an example of the Swift API in use,

```
let notificationCenter = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
notificationCenter.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { granted, error in
    
    if let error = error {
        // Handle the error here.
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    // Enable or disable features based on the authorization.
}
```